# Two special characters

Tags: symbols

I would like to write the two special characters for Medieval Latin transcriptions of "per" and "pro" (see the attached image). Does anybody know if those characters exist? I do not find them. [image]Thanks!

Comment: The comprehensive symbol list does not mention per or pro by name.  I've never seen them before either.

Answer (score 4):

Welcome to TeX.SX! The two symbols `ꝑ` and `ꝓ` are found in the [Latin Extended-D](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_Extended-D) Unicode block. In particular, `Ꝑ` (`U+A750`), `ꝑ` (`U+A751`), `Ꝓ` (`U+A752`) and `ꝓ` (`U+A753`).

Regarding *input*, a Unicode compile engine is recommended: XeTeX or LuaTeX. Regarding *output*, you need to choose a typeface/font that [supports Latin Extended-D](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/block/latin_extended_d/fontsupport.htm). You can choose [Symbola](http://users.teilar.gr/~g1951d/), [Quivira](http://www.quivira-font.com/) or any other fonts you find suitable (see also [the MUFI font page](https://folk.uib.no/hnooh/mufi/fonts/)). **Make sure to read the font license!!**

```
% !TeX program = XeLaTeX
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Symbola_Hinted.ttf}
\begin{document}
per/par: ꝑ: emꝑere (emperere), ꝑler (parler)

pro: ꝓ: ꝓmis (promis), ꝓdome (prodome)
\end{document}
```

[image: Medieval]